# Multiple clojure-liberator decisions reads request body

Tags: clojure, java-io, liberator, slurp

I have one defresource, that is supposed to take POST-requests, validate request body in :malformed-decision, save the body to database in :post!-decision and return the saved body in :handle-created.

```
(defn parse-project [context] (json/read-str
                               (slurp (get-in context [:request :body]))
                               :key-fn keyword))    
(defresource add-new-project
         :malformed? (fn[ctx] (not (project-is-valid (parse-project ctx))))
         :handle-malformed (fn [_] (generate-string (str "Malformed json!")))
         ...
         :post! (fn [ctx] (save-to-db (parse-project ctx))
         :handle-created  (fn [ctx] (... parse-project ...))
```

So my code reads three times the ByteArrayInputStream(that comes from :request :body) with slurp-function. First time works but second time when slurp is called, nil is passed as a param and comes java.io.EOFException: JSON error. I think the reader starts reading where it was left last time.

How could I read the body of the request three times? Or is there nice way to save the result of reading to variable and pass that to other liberator-decisions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `context` can be updated by the outcome of each decision and action functions.  You can parse the project once in `malformed?` and return a map with the parsed project which will be merged into the context so it is available to the following decisions and actions. For example:

```
(defresource add-new-project
  :malformed? (fn[ctx] (let [project (parse-project ctx)]
                         (when (project-is-valid project)
                           {:project project})))
  :handle-malformed (fn [_] (generate-string (str "Malformed json!")))
  :post! (fn [ctx] (save-to-db (:project ctx)))
  :handle-created (fn [ctx] (do-something (:project ctx))))
```

If the project is valid, `:malformed?` returns the `{:project project}`  map which will be merged into the context to be used in the next decisions and actions.
If the project is not valid, it will return `nil` so execution continues in `:handle-malformed`.

For more info on liberator's execution model, see https://clojure-liberator.github.io/liberator/doc/execution-model.html

Comment: Sorry to bring this up from the dead, but at least in Liberator 0.15.x the malformed?-function should return `false` when the request is valid so you cannot just return a truthy value like `{:project project}`. Instead, you need to return `[false {:project project}]` if the request is valid and you want to update the context, and `true` if the request is invalid.